# Is there a way to supress the "rows affected" messages in a T-SQL loop and still get other messages in realtime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I need to delete most of the records from a large table in SQL Server 2008 R2.  There is a huge DELETE trigger on this table that cleans up other tables.  I need to run the deletes in batches so I can see what it is doing, so I wrote a loop to automate the batches but provide status messages.  The problem I am having is that if I use SET NOCOUNT around the DELETE statement, it only gives me the messages after the loop has completed.  I'd just like a way to supress the DELETE statement "rows affected" messages, but still get my PRINT messages in realtime.  I cannot alter the DELETE trigger.  I really just want this to operate like an @ECHO OFF

```
DECLARE @counter INT;
DECLARE @rowstogo INT;
SET @rowstogo = ( SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Customer WHERE Attribute1 <> 11 );
SET @counter = 1;
--while @rowstogo > 0 
WHILE @counter<5  --Test of only 4 iterations
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Pass '+ CAST(@counter as varchar) +': '+ CAST(@rowstogo as varchar)+' records'
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DELETE TOP (100) FROM Customer WHERE Attribute1 <> 11 
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    SET @counter = @counter + 1
    SET @rowstogo = ( select COUNT(1) from Customer where Attribute1 <> 11 )
    PRINT CAST ( @rowstogo as varchar ) + ' records remaining'
    PRINT '--------------------------------'
END
```

Comment: Instead of `PRINT 'foo';` use `RAISERROR('foo',0,1) WITH NOWAIT;` - you still may encounter weird buffer issues with SSMS but it shouldn't happen as frequently. Also don't ever bother with `SET NOCOUNT OFF;` - just always have `SET NOCOUNT ON;`, period.

Comment: Since this is a huge table you might consider changing how you set @ rowstogo in your loop. Something like this would eliminate the need to count that table each trip through the loop. SET @ rowstogo = @ rowstogo - @@rowcount

Comment: I tried SET @ rowstogo = @ rowstogo - @@rowcount, I think it is picking up the last row count from the delete triggers and is giving me odd results.

Comment: You know your doing 100 at a time, use **SET @rowstogo -= 100** instead. As for you original issue. Do you have a programmer that could do this outside of SQL Server? Something in VB or C#? They could create a much better user experience for doing this.

Comment: This is a data purge/cleanup for one of our clients.  The only real user for this is me.  This script may be reused in the future, but it isn't client facing at all.  I just need some way to keep track of where it is at in the process.  

The RaiseError seems to work well.  I added a variable @NumberInBatch so I wouldn't get out of synch with the delete top X and rowstogo-X.  Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running the query from SSMS. You can use global temp table and use a separate Query window to check the running status.

May get a little performance hit due to creating global temp table and inserting into global temp table.

```
    DECLARE @counter INT;
DECLARE @rowstogo INT;

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##rowtable') is not null
    drop table ##rowtable;

-- create global temp table
create table ##rowtable (txt varchar(1000))

SET @rowstogo = ( SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Customer WHERE Attribute1 <> 11 );
SET @counter = 1;
--while @rowstogo > 0 
WHILE @counter<5  --Test of only 4 iterations
BEGIN
    -- PRINT 'Pass '+ CAST(@counter as varchar) +': '+ CAST(@rowstogo as varchar)+' records'

    insert into ##rowtable
    select 'Pass '+ CAST(@counter as varchar) +': '+ CAST(@rowstogo as varchar)+' records'

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DELETE TOP (100) FROM Customer WHERE Attribute1 <> 11 
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    SET @counter = @counter + 1
    SET @rowstogo = ( select COUNT(1) from Customer where Attribute1 <> 11 )

        -- insert into global table
    insert into ##rowtable
    select CAST ( @rowstogo as varchar ) + ' records remaining'

    -- PRINT CAST ( @rowstogo as varchar ) + ' records remaining'
    -- PRINT '--------------------------------'
END

drop table ##rowtable;
```

In a separate Query window in SSMS

```
select * from ##rowtable
```